# Can some explain the Hadoop stack to me?

Tags: hadoop

I am looking to understand and probably play with Hadoop and am looking at the open source projects from [facebook here](http://developers.facebook.com/opensource/). There seems to be way too many to many to wrap my head around. If some one can explain where and how each of these projects fit that would be a great help.

As some background I am thinking about working on a project where the primary driver is images. So want to start things off right when picking a platform (solution). So please feel free to suggest any other technologies as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera has a table that gives equivalents of core Hadoop projects in terms of the Google stack:

```
MapReduce | MapReduce
GFS       | HDFS
BigTable  | HBase
Chubby    | ZooKeeper
Sawzall   | Hive, Pig
```

These, and particularly the first four, are the core components others build on. MapReduce spawns workers as close as possible to the data they will work on. HDFS replicates unstructured data. HBase is a column store. ZooKeeper does service discovery, locking, and leader election. Hive and Pig are high-level query languages, which are implemented as MapReduce computations over HBase data.

There is a lot more to the project ecosystem, from self-contained tools like Avro (serialisation, think protocol buffers), toolkits like Mahout (machine learning), to full-featured products like Nutch (crawler and search engine from which Hadoop was spun off).

Integrators are making distributions of Hadoop and Hadoop-like stacks (Hadoop is loosely coupled and some provide alternatives to important components); the core projects are maintained by the Apache foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. From what I see the question is probably too broad and vague in itself. In essence I am trying to learn how Hadoop and the ecosystem. I guess the best way to go about it is start the project and see how things go.

Comment: @user, I guess I'd start by picking a distribution, maybe Apache's to minimise lock-in, importing some data, and prototyping some treatments, like computing indexes or aggregates.

Comment: Is there a web page that talks about the whole ecosystem by walking through an example?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on this very topic last month:

[The Hadoop Universe](http://www.acunu.com/blogs/sean-owen/hadoop-universe/)

I think it explains all the Hadoop-related Apache projects reasonably, in a paragraph each.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop ecosystem is growing at a very fast pace. There are open source (like Cloudera)/commercial (like MapR) softwares. Start with the [Hadoop ecosystem world map](http://indoos.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/hadoop-ecosystem-world-map/) and go to the next level as required. The article is a bit outdated, but is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a web page that talks about the whole ecosystem by walking through an example? I guess I am looking for something a little more detailed than the one you pointed out.

Comment: I couldn't find exactly what you are looking at, but start with the `world map` and go to the home page/tutorials for each framework to get into the next level. Also, in Hadoop there are alternative framework for almost everything, you might be interested in them also.